# Locator Strategy 'css selector' is not supported for this session

Tags: android, ruby, selenium, mobile, automation

I am trying to locate an element within the body but keep getting the message:

```
Selenium::WebDriver::Error::InvalidSelectorError: Locator Strategy 'css 
selector' is not supported for this session
```

I have tried a number of combinations like:

```
@driver.find_element(:css, "div.ng-scope.ng-binding")
@driver.find_element(:css, 'body.ng-scope')
```

This is the javascript I am using:

```
<body ng-app="nuffieldClassBookingApp" class="ng-scope">
  <!-- uiView: --><div ui-view="" class="ng-scope ng-binding">TEMPLATE 
   YALL ted</div>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script>
</body>
```

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Are you using `Appium`? ["appium accepts only name, xpath and resour-id for individual elements"](https://github.com/appium/appium/issues/5435)

Comment: @mrfreester yes I am. Do you think I should remove the the appium_lib gem from my Gemfile and just use selenium webdriver? The developer is currently building the iOS and android app within Cordova and using the same HTML templates across both iOS and android. When you say appium only accepts the above what's the best way to automate an app when you can't use class, id, tag_name etc etc?

Comment: @driver.id('APACHE CORDOVA) works but @driver.id('Apache Cordova') does not. So you can imagine I'm quite confused right now :-(

Comment: I think appium is the way to go. I couldn't quickly find an updated list of what selector strategies are supported, so some probably have been added since that case I linked above was from 2015. But from the error you're seeing, it looks like css selectors still aren't supported for android. Although this brings up another question, are you testing a native app or a web app?

Comment: I am using Ruby and testing a native app. But there will be part of the app that will bring up the app own internal browser to mimic the website.

Comment: Somebody who has done more testing of native apps would have to chime in, but I wouldn't be surprised if css selectors didn't work for native apps. That might help with some research direction, to find out what selector strategies are used for native apps.